# $scope variable and object in same ng-class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a question.

At the moment I'm using :

```
<div ui-view ng-class="{transparent: loading}" class="{{bodyClass}}"></div>
```

Which is working just fine. But I was wondering if there is a way of doing these actions both in the ng-class atribute.

Something like:

```
<div ui-view ng-class="{transparent: loading, bodyClass}"></div>
```

Or so...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
ng-class="{ 'transparent':loading,
        'bodyClass': condition}"
```

where condition is the `condition` for applying `bodyClass`, which is probably the only reason why you would want to put stuff in ng-class , AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-class="{ 'transparent':loading,
        'bodyClass': true}"
```

simple put `true` in the condition for `bodyClass`

Answer (score 0):

`<div ui-view ng-class="{transparent: loading, 'bodyClass': true}"></div>`

Although the above will add bodyClass as a string and you probably want the value inside it.

You can call a function in ng-class and make their the logic and return a string with the class that you want.

```
<div ui-view ng-class="getTheClass()"></div>
$scope.getTheClass = function() { 
   var class = $scope.bodyClass;
   if ($scope.loading) {
        class = class + ' transparent';
   }
   return class;
}
```